# MS-Access SQL statement to update table based on query result

Tags: ms-access

I am trying my hand at MS-Access and am self-taught up to this point so please be patient with me. I have researched this to the best of my ability but still can't get it to work.

I have a table and I am populating fields based on query results.  My first SQL statement works but my second one does not, it gives me a

> "Type mismatch in expression"

error. The first query has the same number of records as the table while the second query will have a different number of records depending on which table is referenced.

I want the table updated from the second query where ever the table ID and the query `arcfilenumber` match, any non-matches would be skipped.

```
'Runs the query for sorting the weld parameter data
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Temp_Query"

'Code to copy data to proper table
Dim mySQL5 As String

mySQL5 = "UPDATE [" & tblDESTINATION & "] INNER JOIN [temp_query] ON([" & tblDESTINATION & _
         "].ID = [temp_query].expr4) SET [" & tblDESTINATION & "].[S_" & FIELD & "] = [temp_query].expr1"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute mySQL5
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Temp_Query"

'This sets and calls a query that will get the Weld Numbers associated with the selected jig.
'and moves the weld information to the proper table
Dim mySQL9 As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qdfOLD As String
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qWELD_NO")
With qdf
qdfOLD = .SQL
.SQL = Replace(.SQL, "TEMP", Me.JIG)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qWELD_NO"

' Code to do stuff with SQL-string/query

mySQL9 = "UPDATE [" & tblDESTINATION & "] INNER JOIN [qweld_no] ON([" & tblDESTINATION & _
     "].ID = [qweld_no].arcfilenumber) SET [" & tblDESTINATION & "].[W_" & FIELD & "] = [qweld_no].weld_no"

MsgBox mySQL9
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute mySQL9
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

.SQL = qdfOLD ' Reset SQL to old setting
End With
Set qdf = Nothing

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qWELD_NO"
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The resulting SQL statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE [DUWYP-48670] INNER JOIN [qweld_no] ON([DUWYP-48670].ID = [qweld_no].arcfilenumber) SET [DUWYP-48670].[W_5_26_2017] = [qweld_no].weld_no
```

EDIT2:

I have changed the table field type to number and created an expresion in the query to put in 1s and 0s, still no go.  I moved the SQL instruction out of the WITH code and it still doesn't work.  I can't figure out why it works just a few code lines before but not after.  Is it because of the different number of records?  Should I open a recordset and loop through instead of SQL?

Comment: Is this Access or SQL Server??? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, ms-access, I'm trying to make an SQL statement to do the job.

Comment: The error indicates linking fields are not same data type.

Comment: Destination field is set to short text and the generated query result is a mix of letters and numbers.  For the part that is working it is putting query generated numbers into a numbers field.

Comment: do the query manually, then look at it in SQL view and start from that.

Comment: If everything is the correct data type the only thing I can see obviously wrong is that there isn't a space after `ON`

Comment: I have already posted the SQL statement and you can see from the code that it is in the same format as the working SQL statement.  The difference is the referenced query.  I have figured out that the Type Mismatch is in the  [arcfilenumber] field.  It is generating a number by a mathmatical calculation but it is creating the field as short text.  I can get it to work by changing the query to a make table query and then changing the [autonumber] field type to number.  Now I would like to have the query field set to number but don't know how.

Comment: You could cast them both as long numbers - `ON (CLNG([" & tblDESTINATION & _
     "].ID) = CLNG([qweld_no].arcfilenumber))`

Comment: There we go!  Thank you Darren, that worked perfectly.  I was stumped trying to get a data type to a query expression, I never thought to set it individually in the SQL.  Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the ideal solution.  I'd advise getting the fields in the database table in the correct format to start with.

Saying that though, it's often beyond our control how the data arrives so we have to coerce the data into something that can be used.

In this case the text can be converted to the long data type by using `CLNG`.

```
UPDATE  [DUWYP-48670] INNER JOIN [qweld_no] ON 
            (CLNG([DUWYP-48670].ID) = CLNG([qweld_no].arcfilenumber)) 
SET     [DUWYP-48670].[W_5_26_2017] = [qweld_no].weld_no
```

This link lists some of the other data types that can be used:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions.
Note - not all the types in the link can be used by Access (it's just the first link I found and deals with VB rather than VBA).